# Trying to invoke a virtual method

Tags: android

Why do I always get the below problem when I am trying to get values by editing text in the database?
The error always points to this line:

`SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Anyone encountered a similar error and solved it?

Comment: pls add your code

Comment: Please, share you code and read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you initialize DataBaseHelper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**initialize your database helper class**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.surveyinstruction);

DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

//other code

}
```